# teamsでoutlookに登録されている他の人の予定表を見る方法はありますか？

Tags: microsoft-teams

Temasを社内で使用しているのですが、そのメンバーの予定をoutlookを開かなくても見る方法はありますか？
自分の予定は予定表タブで見れますが、同様に他人のメンバーを見る事は出来ませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

検索すると以下の3件(+1件)くらいが見つかりました。

アドオンの商業ソフトでこんなものがあるようです。
[Microsoft Teams対応共有予定アプリ「ScheduleLook for Microsoft Teams」](http://www.bbsystem.co.jp/product/schedulelook/)

他人の個人の予定表では無く、PowerShellをコマンドラインで使うことでグループ予定表は何とか出来るらしいです。
[Microsoft Teams ：作成したチームに接続されている Office 365 グループのグループ予定表を利用するのは厳しい](https://art-break.net/tech/?p=5537)

記事内容としては何か出来そうですが、実際にどうなっているかは良く判らないもの。
[Teams内でシームレスなスケジュール管理をする方法](https://businesschatmaster.com/teams/teams-schedule)

参考：
他人の予定表そのものは見えないけれども予定が空いているかは判るらしいですね。
[超便利！TeamsとOutlookの連携でもっと業務効率化](https://licensecounter.jp/office365/blog/2019/12/teams-outlook.html)